# AS3 - Function not working always

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a button that opens up a shop. This shop has some text in it that displays the cash information for your player. When I create the shop inside a .as class I make the text display. It will work if I call the function when I click a shop button, but if I call it when I first create the shop, it doesn't work. Here is my code and please explain why this might not work.

```
public function UGShop(){
updateStats();
}

public function updateStats(){
    CashTXT.text = String("$ " + cashamount);
}
}
```

My cash is already in my shop.
This is just a portion of my code.

Comment: Are you certain that `cashamount` has a value assigned to it when you call it immediately? What happens if you `trace(cashamount);` ?

Comment: Please give some more details, what is the behavior that occurs, that is does it display $null or do you get nothing in the display.  Also are you using Flex if so the creationPolicy/life cycle of Flex events will play a role here.  Also are you using the flash player debug version, please verify here (scroll down to bottom): http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/find-version-flash-player.html

Comment: As for reasons this might not work... CashTXT is not yet created, cashamount is not yet set.  Providing more code will help get your question answered more quickly and honestly no one here cares about stealing your code, while I realize too much code can bury the issue in this case it's too little.  I have to guess what tool you're using to build this what CashTXT is, where cashamount is populated where UGShop is created and what actually happens when it "doesn't work"

Answer (score 1):

1. `cashtxt` isn't created or is not on stage.
2. `cashamount` has no value

If it's something else, you didn't supply any info for it

If you run into these things often, try looking into [Monster Debugger](http://demonsterdebugger.com/), it can tell you the state of any object on stage.